# keep getting an internal server error 500. Never able to connect to mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi I've spent the past week trying to submit a html form to a mysql database.  But I'm constantly getting an internal server error of 500.  Everytime I submit the form, I get a white page and an error on the console.

The error on the console only says:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://172.31.1.18/insert.php**

I'm using linux.  I have my own private server which works fine.  PHP and mySQL are installed.  I can view php pages on my browser ok.  I can access mySQL via a command line ok.

this is the php file:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("my server ID", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname']);
$email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

my form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Records">
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the server error log? What does it say?

Comment: What is the full error

Comment: that's all it says:
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Have you made sure that you are able to access mysql with those credentials? Your example shows `mysqli_connect("my server ID", "root", "", "demo");`, but what you have in your code might not be working.

Comment: Thank you.  What exactly do I need to put in?

I use mysqli_connect("172.00.0.00", "root", "*************", "demo");

with 172 being IP server number,  root being root, and ****** being password and demo being database name.

Comment: I don't even know why my post has been marked down?  I keep getting an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an issue with apache2.  Sudo service restart apache sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Give write access to the folder that contains your files (mainly the php ones).

if you are using Linux server, write access can be given to the folder recursively using the following command:

> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www

**Note:** 777 permission is not recommended to give it to all files and folders, but it is OK for a development phase.